# Sorting array of words by pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am having a set of strings in array, and by pure javascript I am trying to sort them and print them out. I am only getting blank array. Can someone help me out?

```
<script> 
(function(){
    var a = ["AB", "SU", "MN", "AC", "QA", "DZ", "CM", "EP"];
    var b = [];
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        var temp = a[i].split('')[0];
        for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
            if (temp < b[j].split('')[0]){
                b[j] = push(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(b);
})();
</script>
```

Also I need to take in account comparision of second, third, fourth characters if they exist, but I am doomed even in fist letter comparison in string. Pls, take that also in account.

Comment: Use the [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

Comment: care a fiddle sir?

Comment: I don't know why you're splitting up the strings. You can compare string with just `a[i] < b[j]`.

Comment: Don't use fiddle, use [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)

Comment: Will it help compare whole strings with each other in array sorting??

Comment: Yes, it will compare the whole strings with each other. This is very basic Javascript.

Comment: Try `console.log("ABC" < "AEX");`

Comment: The `.sort()` function by default sorts by string lexicographic order, so `a.sort()` is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is just calling

a.sort()

PS: sort is going to update your array (not just returning a copy of your array sorted)

Comment: without sort function

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.
**EDIT**
Consider comments i was wrong a little bit. Now all fine.

```
var a = ["AB", "SU", "MN", "AC", "QA", "DZ", "CM", "EP"];
var b = a.sort();
//also can use reverse here.
console.log(b);
```

And here is jsbin

https://jsbin.com/xikamitole/1/edit?html,js,console

Hope this helps.

Comment: The callback here is incorrect. The callback passed to `.sort()` should return a negative number if the first parameter should sort before the second, 0 if they have the same sort order, and 1 if the second should sort before the first.

Comment: The comparison function is supposed to return a number, `v > k` returns a boolean.

Comment: Well in here we have strings. So consider example all valid.

Comment: But, I am getting correct result man! @Pointy - Then how is this giving correct result????

Comment: Ok...i see your point. Yep my a little bit incorrect. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: Sometimes bad code works despite being incorrect. That doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Ty guys for fixing my issue. And glad that @Peterson got his answer.

Comment: assign to `b` is useless, you are just copying the `a` reference to `b`. After that, if you modify `b` elements you ll modify `a` too. So just do `a.sort()` as @Rachid wrote